# How to custome validate limit POST a file size to Django Server through Tastypie API

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I don't know how to get file size to verify limitation file size. Please see my custom validate below.

```
class CustomFileSizeValidation(Validation):
"""
The custom validation checks for uploading file size (2KB)
"""
def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
    if not bundle.data:
        return {'__all__': 'Missing data, please include all fields'}

    errors = {}
    fileData = bundle.data.get('testFileField')

    # Very simple validate file size large than 2KB for testing
    if fileData.file.size > (2 * 1024):
        errors['testFileField']='Limited file size'

    valid_extensions = ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']
    if not fileData.file.content_type in valid_extensions:
        errors['testFileField'] = "Not support file type"

    return errors
```

Please help me how to get file size & get content type for validating.

Thanks!
Trong.

Comment: Hello, who can help me?

Comment: What's the issue? You getting an error? What does `fileData.file.size` contain?